# Symfony with NelmioSolariumBundle - how to log http 500 errors

Tags: symfony, logging, solr, solarium, nelmiosolariumbundle

how can I configure or what to do if I want to log using Nelmiosolariumbundle under Symfony when I get e.g. http 500 Error.

I have in prod.log message of error. But there is missing query to SOLR - so I can't configure what was requested and how to fix it.

Can anybody provide advice please ?

thank you
Milan

Comment: Do you have access to the solr-admin page? There is a "logging" section which maybe provides more information.

Comment: Yes, you are right but there is just error and not e.g. query string which produced it. So I can't whit core it is. Which functionality it is. Etc. I can't allow FULL logging under SOLR (disc space and hight load could be than). So I want to log it under application, but only on error. Especially this one.